# Unable to make header be at top of page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header for my page, but it will not go to the top of the page. I've tried the CSS reset, and it didn't work, and I've tried moving the units of height to %, px, and vh, but that didn't work either.

CSS:

```
<style>
#heading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0vh;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(140,120,83,0.96);
    color: rgba(8,37,150, 0.8);
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="heading"> Anything </h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<h1>` through `<h5>` tags have **built in margins**.

You need to remove the margin from your `h1` tag:

```
#heading {
position: fixed;
top: 0vh;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgba(140,120,83,0.96);
color: rgba(8,37,150, 0.8);
margin:0; /* added this */
}
```

In addition, make certain your CSS is *closed correctly*. The CSS in your question is not closed.